# how to select element by linq to xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

how i can select `ip` and `port` elements form this xml file by linq to xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings>
  <IncomingConfig>
    <ip>10.100.101.18</ip>
    <port>5060</port>
  </IncomingConfig>
  <Device>
    <username>tarek</username>
    <AgentName>tarek</AgentName>
    <password>ffff</password>

  </Device>
  <Device>
    <username>adf</username>
    <AgentName>adf</AgentName>
    <password>fadsf</password>

  </Device>
</settings>
```

and i write this code but not work

```
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(CONFIGURATION_FULL_PATH);
            var port = int.Parse(doc.XPathSelectElement("port").Value);
            var localIpAdres = doc.XPathSelectElement("ip").Value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have loaded your file into the `doc` variable you simply need

```
string localIpAddress = doc.Root.Element("IncomingConfig").Element("ip").Value;
string port = doc.Root.Element("IncomingConfig").Element("port").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
doc.XPathSelectElement("//port").Value
```

The argument must be an XPath expression.